# Jquery : display list option under icon after clicking on the same icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a list option dynamically when I click on the right icons. The list option should be displayed under the clicked icon and disappear if the pointer is not on the icon.

For example, if I click on the first icon, a list option appear with values : EN, FR, DE, ES under the first icon. If i click on the 2nd icon, a list option appear with values : EN, FR under the 2nd icon.

The last thing is that I want to add a href with each option of the list and when I choose an option, it open the link in a new window.

[image]

What is the best solution to make it possible ?

Comment: Please add the code samples of what you have tried so far.

Comment: unfortunately, i have no code samples, i am a junior in jquery. The only thing I can add is that icons are in a table inside a td.